# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://travel.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 2):

This seem more information about the nominees link does somehow not work for me:

http://elections.stackexchange.com/#travel.stackexchange

Comment: Nor for me. Maybe this deserves a meta post of it's own? I don't think that site got updated with the fact that Travel graduated.

Answer (score 1):

And the results were (almost four years ago):

[image: results]